# How to play a .mp3 file from a folder discord bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I have a music bot in Discord and I'd like to add custom songs it can play. The problem is that there are a lot of albums I want to add and, let's say that having 100+ .mp3 files in one folder would be confusing to manage.
So how do I specify a directory for `voice.play(FFmpegPCMAudio('Traveller.mp3))` to play a file from a 
different folder? For example, I could use different album folders to play .mp3's from them.

```
@bot.command()
async def wake(ctx):
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    try:
        voice = await channel.connect()
    except:
        pass
    voice.play(FFmpegPCMAudio('Traveller.mp3'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To specify a specific path to a file, you can use the relative path:

```py
voice.play(FFmpegPCMAudio("path/to/Traveller.mp3"))
```

Or you can use an absolute path:

```py
voice.play(FFmpegPCMAudio("A:/path/to/Traveller.mp3"))
```

Comment: since Traveller.mp3 was originally in a folder named "Music", I tried using `voice.play(FFmpegPCMAudio('Music/Traveller.mp3')), but got an error that there was no such path/file.

Comment: Is that `Music` folder in the same folder as your bot's scripts?

Comment: Nevermind, I was trying to use the shortcut on my desktop to access the folder, silly me. After using an absolute path it works perfectly! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction a second time!